# NULL session in Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

i moved an application from prod to a dev server and now the sessions in my web service won't save. I'm thinking it might be a setting in the IIS? but i'm not sure where to look.

here is what broke:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
public static List<RequestType> GetRequestType(string itemNo, int requestTypeID)
{
    UserSession usObj = (UserSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSessionObj"];
```

usObj  is coming out NULL

Comment: It's always null or sometimes null?

Comment: Have you set <sessionstate mode="inproc"/>, or some or some other mode, in the webconfig?

Comment: Shouldn't the session property read `EnableSession=true`?